# How to upgrade kubectl server version to v1.21

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to upgrade kubectl server version to be compatible with client version to get rid of Selflink issue that has been deprecated after kubernetes v1.21. How can I do this?

```
PS C:\> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.7", GitCommit:"e1d093448d0ed9b9b1a48f49833ff1ee64c05ba5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-03T00:20:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Where is your cluster running? are you using any local cluster like `kind`?

Answer (score 1):

Update your kubernetes cluster that you are using. You see the api server version there.